# How to get name of foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I have a list view of device ports and each device port belongs to a device:

**device.rb**

```
has_many :device_ports, :foreign_key => "device_id"
```

**device_port.rb**

```
belongs_to :device
```

**device_port_controller.rb**

```
def list
    @device_ports = DevicePort.paginate(:all, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 100, :order => "name")
    @devices = Device.find(:all)
end
```

**list.rhtml**

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Device</th>
    </tr>

    <%= render :partial => 'device_port/list_item', :collection => @device_ports %>
</table>
```

_**list_item.rhtml**

```
<tr>
    <td><a href='/device_port/update/<%= list_item.id %>'><%= list_item.name %></a></td>
    <td><%= list_item.device_id %></td>
</tr>
```

So I am displaying the `device_id` from the `device_ports` table but I actually want to display the `name` column of the `devices` table instead.

I have done something very similar and probably slightly more difficult elsewhere in my app where I have a preselected dropdown with the correct device name selected but I can't seem to figure out how to do it outwith the context of a select menu.

I have the devices in the `@devices` variable in the controller above and was trying to look that up using the `list_item.device_id` but it didn't seem to work.

It's probably quite a straightforward thing but I just can't seem to find the proper way of getting the desired result.

Comment: as device_ports belongs_to device so `list_item.device.name` Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as device_ports belongs_to device so `list_item.device.name` Thanks!

Comment: damn it, I knew it would be something easy but I just didn't have a clue about the syntax, thanks for saving my sanity!

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this out in the console but it should work. You can call `columns` on your model which returns an array.

So, what I just used my User model:

```
User.columns[0].name #=> 'id'
```

Presumably yours will be

```
Device.columns[x].name
```

EDIT: I read the the question as "name [of the] column"